# Data repopulate using jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div like below in HTML page:

When I click on any div I am saving the span text in DB and when again come back to the same page I am getting the response as saved text. on the basis of the text I need repopulate the clicked view.

I am adding all the code I have used, not able to populate the data.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class='score score-exel'>
        <div class='arrow'></div><span class='scoreText'> 750-850 Excellent</span>
    </div>
    <div class='score score-good'>
        <div class='arrow'></div><span class='scoreText'> 700-749 Good</span>
    </div>
    <div class='score score-ok'>
        <div class='arrow'></div><span class='scoreText'> 650-699 OK</span>
    </div>
    <div class='score score-fair'>
        <div class='arrow'></div><span class='scoreText'> 600-649 Fair</span>
    </div>
    <div class='score score-poor'>
        <div class='arrow'></div><span class='scoreText'> 300-599 Poor</span>
    </div>
    <div class='btnHold'>
        <button class='btn btn-success idkBtn'>I Don't Know</button>
        <button class='btn btn-success submitBtn'>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the below code for variable I am adding the selected value when the user clicks the div.

```
$('.score').bind('click', function(){
    $('.arrow').hide();
    $(this).find('.arrow').fadeIn();
    userCreditScore = $(this).find('span').text().toString();
});
```

In below code I am getting response and trying to repopulate the data but not possible.

```
function fillData(){
    var response = nav.scorm.getResponse('CREDIT_SCORE');
    if(response != ''){
        var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

          *** used many codes like below but not useful
//$('.score').find('span.scoreText:contains('+jsonData.CREDIT_SCORE+')').parent().css('display', 'block');
        //$('.score').find('span.scoreText:contains('+jsonData.CREDIT_SCORE+')').parent().click();
    }
```

Comment: what data you're getting from server back? if you do console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(response)) what d u see?

Comment: first time if i clicked the div <div class='score score-good'>  i will get response as " 700-749 Good".

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're missing the callback in your `nav.scorm.getResponse` method - if it's a AJAX call. Check the commented code you have:

```
//here we do the request
var response = nav.scorm.getResponse('CREDIT_SCORE');

//this line and is executed immediately, while 'response' var is still undefined
    if(response != ''){
```

So depending on code you have in nav.scorm.getResponse you might have smth like

```
nav.scorm.getResponse('CREDIT_SCORE', function(response){
  if(response != ''){
    //put it to DOM
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

**UPD**

The problem was with the spaces in your scores texts,
`' 600-649 Fair'` won't work, while `'600-649 Fair'` will do.

Check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/v3gxy8rL/

Comment: I cross checked, response is getting fine. once i got response i need to populate data on that value.

Comment: can you add **console.log(response)** after that line - **var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);** and say what it outputs

Comment: i am getting output as {"CREDIT_SCORE":" 600-649 Fair"}

Comment: var id = $('.score').find('span.scoreText:contains('+jsonData.CREDIT_SCORE.trim()+')').parent().css('display', 'block'); used like this but not working. i am displaying the text but i need to display arrow next to it. that is not working.     In my old code i am using $(this).find('.arrow').fadeIn();

Comment: NO, you're triming the value that you are searching for but not in the list of elements in DOM; those all **<span class='scoreText'> 300-599 Poor</span>** need to be changed to **<span class='scoreText'>300-599 Poor</span>**. You should use CSS for padding/margins, not spaces in HTML tags

Comment: I changed to **<span class='scoreText'>300-599 Poor</span>**. not working. You got my issue right?

Comment: For me also text is displaying, i have an <div class='arrow'> where an image has to be highlighted or dispalyed, but it's not working.